# Clicks on Safari iOS function differently than on PC with ng-click with ripple animation

Tags: javascript, ios, css, angularjs, safari

I have a weird issue with **ng-click** on Safari on iOS. I have three button with ng-click handler with animation on hover.

```
<div class="switcher switcher--3buttons">
    <button ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items track by $index" ng-click="$ctrl.onChange({ index: $index })"
        class="switcher-tab is-active"
        ng-class="{ 'is-active': $ctrl.chosen == item.value || $ctrl.selectedIndex === $index }"
        ng-disabled="item.disabled">
        <span class="tab-text">D</span>
    </button>
    <button ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items track by $index" ng-click="$ctrl.onChange({ index: $index })"
        class="switcher-tab"
        ng-class="{ 'is-active': $ctrl.chosen == item.value || $ctrl.selectedIndex === $index }"
        ng-disabled="item.disabled">
        <span class="tab-text">W</span></button>
    <button ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items track by $index" ng-click="$ctrl.onChange({ index: $index })"
        class="switcher-tab"
        ng-class="{ 'is-active': $ctrl.chosen == item.value || $ctrl.selectedIndex === $index }"
        ng-disabled="item.disabled">
        <span class="tab-text">M</span>
   </button>
```

The issue is with the long click vs short clicks. On PC both have the desired effect - hover animation with the change in the chosen value. On Safari you have the correct behavior when clicking lightly on track-pad, longer clicks result in correct hover animation, but with not the correct change in the chosen value.

One can easily reproduce the issue [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/HmUnnAU3Orx288lOhF86?p=preview)

I have a suspicion about [Force Touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/RespondingtoForceTouchEventsfromJavaScript.html), but I am not sure as I don't have the bubble animation.

I am totally open to suggestions how to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurred on Safari because of the inner span inside the button with ripple effect animation. The fix is pure CSS:

```
button > span {
   pointer-events: none; 
}
```

Comment: That is a great hint also for other ripple animation libraries!